# ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (244,2) into shape (244,)

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, seaborn

I am trying to plot a simple Seaborn plot.

```py
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')

#Plotting our subplots dividing with smoker
sns.relplot(x = "total_bill", y = "tip", hue = "smoker", col = "size", data = tips)

#Showing our plots in a proper format
plt.show()
```

But it is showing an error

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (244,2) into shape (244,)
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be a bug with the 'size' column name. That's strange, because `tips` is one of seaborn's typical example datasets.

It works as expected when that column gets renamed:

```py
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')
tips.rename(columns={'size': 'size_renamed'}, inplace=True)
sns.relplot(x='total_bill', y='tip', hue='smoker', col='size_renamed', data=tips)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: I don't think its anything to do with the dataset. This happens in versions ≥ 0.11.0. There were a lot of changes from 0.10.1 so I'm not sure exactly where the problem is

Comment: The relevant part of the dataset is that is has a column named `'size'` and that `col=...` is happy with any column name except for `row='size'`. `row='size'` also gives the same strange error message when there isn't a column with that name.